# Sometimes, I cannot add primitives in blender 2.8

Tags: modeling

I've already found a fix (restart blender) but is there any other way of getting blender to "refresh" when hotkeys sometimes stop working?

Comment: If any hotkey stopped working it is supposed to be a bug so please file a bug report. *Main Menu > Help > Report a Bug*...